# how do you re-organize cells in R

Tags: r

I have this df:

```
structure(list(YEAR = c("2007", "2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", 
"2008", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2008"), MONTH = c("12", "10", 
"11", "01", "03", "05", "06", "08", "09", "10"), TOTAL = c(85055988L, 
21567576L, 82763640L, 91007916L, 93936288L, 99646750L, 90091044L, 
98811936L, 96888876L, 100909236L)), .Names = c("YEAR", "MONTH", 
"TOTAL"), row.names = c("24801", "33863", "34055", "24973", "25046", 
"25295", "25384", "25541", "25861", "27319"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to organize this data frame as follows:

```
YEAR JAN  FEB  MARCH .... DEC
2009 TOTAL VALUE FOR EACH month goes to each corresponding cells.
```

any ideas how I could easily accomplish this in R?

Comment: Look at package reshape2.

Answer (score 1):

`dcast` and `xtabs` are among the options to consider:

```
xtabs(TOTAL ~ YEAR + MONTH, df)
#       MONTH
# YEAR          01        03        05        06        08        09        10        11        12
#   2007         0         0         0         0         0         0  21567576  82763640  85055988
#   2008  91007916  93936288  99646750  90091044  98811936  96888876 100909236         0         0

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, YEAR ~ MONTH, value.var="TOTAL", fun.aggregate=sum)
#   YEAR       01       03       05       06       08       09        10       11       12
# 1 2007        0        0        0        0        0        0  21567576 82763640 85055988
# 2 2008 91007916 93936288 99646750 90091044 98811936 96888876 100909236        0        0
```

Comment: thank you for this. Is there a function to use, if I wanted to see the difference between the same month in different years? For example, I like to see the difference between 2010 and 2011 for JUNE?

Comment: @user1471980, why not just use normal subsetting? Assuming the output of the `dcast` step was a `data.frame` called "df.wide", you can try something like `with(df.wide, df.wide[YEAR == "2011", "06"] - df.wide[YEAR == "2010", "06"])`. Of course, I would actually also suggest using a real time-series data structure if you really want to simplify your life!

Comment: how would you do this if your data comprised of 10 some years and you need to track the difference between the same months for each year?

Comment: @user1471980, As I indicated in my previous comment, I would use an actual time series object or functions from packages like "zoo" or "xts" that let you work with time series data more conveniently.